# java inheritance when one of the fields is fixed

Tags: java, inheritance

An inheritance question.

I have 1 superclass and 2 subclasses.

Problem:
Can I use inheritance for the field **age** and method **getAge()**?
What confuses me is that the field age in Dog class is **fixed** (15) and not a parameter.
I would like to move method getAge() to the superclass but the fixed value of Dog's age confuses me.
What to do when a field in one (sub)class is fixed to a value and it's not in the other. Can you still use inheritance?
How to solve this?

```
//Super class:
    public class Animal
    {
       private String name;

       public Animal(String nam)
       {
          name = nam;
       }

       public void displayName("This animal is: " + name);
    }

//Subclass 1:
public class Cat extends Animal
{
private int age;

       public Cat(String nam, int a)
       {
          super(nam);
          age = a;
       }

       public int getAge()
       {
           return age;
       }
}

//Subclass 2:
public class Dog extends Animal
{
private int age;

       public Dog(String nam)
       {
          super(nam)
          age = 15;
       }

       public int getAge()
       {
           return age;
       }
}
```

Matt

Comment: A dog is always 15 years old.. nice!

Comment: @A-C: That's exactly what I'd like to do. But what do you do with dog's age being fixed? You can't put it as a parameter to the constructor.

Comment: I know dogs that aren't 15 years old, believe me...

Comment: @user1552294 Well since you updated your question, I thought my comment wasn't needed anymore :) Anyways, if you can't change Animal at all, there is nothing to inherit age-wise. But if you can, the answers provided seem good.

Comment: Since you seem to fix the age of a Dog, you better have it as a static  field constant, so that there's no room for a change in the age.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
public abstract class Animal
{
   private String name;
   private int age;

   public Animal(String nam)
   {
      name = nam;
   }

   public void displayName() 
   {
      System.out.println("This animal is: " + name);
   }

   public abstract int getAgeInAnimalYears();
}

public class Cat extends Animal
{
       private int age;

       public Cat(String nam, int a)
       {
          super(nam);
          age = a;
       }

       @Override
       public int getAgeInAnimalYears()
       {
           return age * 9;
       }
}

public class Dog extends Animal
{
       private int age;

       public Dog(String nam)
       {
          super(nam)
          age = 15;
       }

       @Override
       public int getAgeInAnimalYears()
       {
           return age * 7;
       }
}
```

This uses an abstract class ( http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html ) for `Animal`. Note that this means you cannot instantiate `Animal` objects anymore, they have to be `Cat`s or `Dog`s or any other subclass of `Animal`. I think that is a reasonable design choice, but if for some reason you need to instantiate pure `Animal`s, you could leave those as a normal class and throw an exception instead:

```
public class Animal
{
   private String name;
   private int age;

   public Animal(String nam)
   {
      name = nam;
   }

   public void displayName() 
   {
       System.out.println("This animal is: " + name); 
   }

   public int getAgeInAnimalYears() {
      throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
   }
}
```

### What's great about that?

To address your question about code reuse: You are already saving space by implementing `displayName()` only once - imagine if that were a much more complicated function that still worked the same for all animals, and also imagine three more sublasses, suddenly you save a big bunch of code. Much more attractive, however, is the following feature that inheritance allows you to do:

```
public class Zoo
{
    private ArrayList<Animal> list = new ArrayList<Animal>();

    public void addAnimal(Animal a)
    {
        list.add(a);
    }

    public void everyoneSayHello()
    {
        for (Animal a : list) {
            a.displayName();
            System.out.println("It is " + a.getAgeInAnimalYears() + \
                               " animal-years old!")
        }
    }
 }
```

You can now add `Dog`s, `Cat`s and whatever to your list, and when you call `everyoneSayHello()`, [Polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_in_object-oriented_programming) automatically calls the right `getAgeInAnimalYears()` for you! Without inheritance, this only works with large `if`/`case` blocks which are hard to extend. With inheritance, you just add another class that extends `Animal`, no need to change any other code!

Comment: Question: What would be advantage of using abstract class and inheritance here? I was hoping to eliminate code duplication but the amount of code has not improved. I do have further things to do with this code and perhaps that's where benefits of such design using abstract classes show beneficial?

Comment: @user1552294 I have updated my answer to address your questions. However I'd still recommend you get a good Java textbook with an emphasis on OO programming. When learning these concepts, it's good to have the big picture in mind as you go along rather than trying to fit together small pieces. Just my 2 cents, ymmv :)

Comment: Yeah. Thanks us2012. I looked into this a bit more in the meantime and it makes a lot of sense. Mainly I was confused about the difference between a regular superclass and an abstract class as well as code reuse. I am actually working on a different code (this one here represents my question) and there I have now been able to implement yuor suggestions and can see that in the big picture it makes a lot of sense. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question you want to ask.. what you want to do is change `Animal` as follows

```
public class Animal
{
    ....
    protected int age;
    public int getAge()
    {
        return age;
    }
}
```

And remove the definitions for `age` and `getAge` from the subclasses- This is because I assume (and you want to as well I think) that all animals have age, but they could be differently managed for different animals, like in your case.

The rest of your code **need not change** (I have made age protected so that it can be set in subclasses), though instead of the way you did it, I would use a setter `setAge` and customize that as you want (ignore the age and set 15 in the case of dog for example)

Comment: But then, any specific animal would return its age in dog-years/cat-years/etc, whereas an instance of `Animal` returns an age in standard human years. I don't think that is a good model for the (admittedly somewhat artificial) problem domain.

Comment: @us2012 That is also beyond the questions scope.. but I agree, your solution handles that better.

Comment: It is beyond the scope of this particular question, but I thought I would mention it since the problem of functionality that is to be provided for all subclasses, but cannot sensibly be implemented for the superclass is a confusing one for people learning about inheritance (it certainly was for me).

Answer (score 0):

You don't expose an API method to mutate the age in either case. You can move both the field and the getter to the superclass, and since age is never modified, it will work as you are expecting.

If you were to add a setter (or any method that modifies age) to the superclass, all you would need to do is override that method in the Dog class and take the appropriate action (e.g. do nothing, throw an UnsupportedOperationException, etc).